# Che cos'è "un mento puntato e rientrato"?

Tags: meaning

In *Il fu Mattia Pascal* di Luigi Pirandello si legge (nel capitolo 8):

> Intravidi da quel primo scempio qual mostro fra breve sarebbe scappato fuori dalla necessaria e radicale alterazione dei connotati di Mattia Pascal. Ed ecco una nuova ragione d’odio per lui! Il mento piccolissimo, puntato e rientrato, ch’egli aveva nascosto per tanti e tanti anni sotto quel barbone, mi parve un tradimento. Ora avrei dovuto portarlo scoperto, quel cosino ridicolo!

Sono riuscito a trovare che cos'è "un mento rientrato"; vuol dire "concavo": https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/R/rientrato.shtml

Ma "puntato" non mi dice nulla. Da quel che ho potuto trovare, la parola "puntare" ha qualcosa di comune con "pungere", "battere": per esempio, le punte delle forbici, cioè la loro parte con cui si potrebbe colpire qualcosa o qualcuno. Forse è un mento acuto, come se ci fosse il rischio di pungere qualcosa con questo mento come con una spada?

Come dovrei immaginare il mento di cui narra Mattia Pascal? Grazie.

**Aggiornamento:** Mi dà da pensare che "puntato" e "rientrato" qua sembrino dire lo stesso, forse ho capito male qualcosa, donde la domanda.

Comment: Che vuol dire “UPD”?

Comment: @DaG credo significhi "update"

Comment: Puntato secondo me significa proprio "appuntito"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi grazie!

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ah, giusto, grazie!

Comment: @Evgeniy: Mi sono permesso di correggere qualcosa qua e là nella tua grammatica; forse può essere utile.

Comment: @DaG sì, grazie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00000978.jpg), "puntato" è un aggettivo che significa

> Che ha una punta, che finisce in punta; aguzzo, acuminato, puntuto.

Non è, però, un aggettivo molto usato nell'italiano moderno: un'espressione più usuale per fare questa descrizione sarebbe "mento puntuto".

Per quanto riguarda ["rientrato"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI16/00238.jpg), l'accezione adatta alla descrizione del mento di una persona è la seguente:

> Situato  o  inserito  indietro  o  all'interno  rispetto  a  una  linea  di  riferimento;  arretrato.  – An­che: posto in un incavo.

Il dizionario dà un esempio letterario di Moravia, in questo caso nella descrizione della bocca di un personaggio:

> Aveva  un  viso  di  vecchio,  con  la  bocca rientrata  tra  il  naso  adunco  e  il  mento  sporgente.

Qui si tratta di un mento rientrato, cioè, un mento spostato all'indietro rispetto alla posizione considerata normale.

Comment: Grazie, è stata molto utile la tua ricerca!..

Comment: Evidentemente il mento di Mattia Pascal per intero fu rientrato, insieme con la bocca. Altrimenti non potrebbe essere puntuto allo stesso tempo.

Answer (score 0):

"Puntato" potrebbe, forse con libertà di prosa, riferirsi all'atto di "aver subito l'effetto (o la sorte)" di una punta, cioè essere appuntito, a punta. Una parola vicina e più corretta è "puntuto".

Comment: “Correggiamo” Pirandello...? :)

Comment: @DaG ci mancherebbe altro... un grande scrittore non è soggetto alle regole normali. Ma questo sito non è un romanzo, ho cercato di essere completo nella spiegazione, che è soltanto la mia personale opinione e quindi potrei sbagliarmi.